# Dynamic object properties

Tags: php

I've got a question, is it possible to add dynamical properties to object like

```
private function get_invoice_info($data, array $rel)
{
    foreach ($data as $info)
    {
        foreach($rel as $val)
        {
           $info->$val->$val->etc;
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Problem is that object properties can be an object and has it own properties or relations.

Like `$info->contract` and `$info->contract->contractor`.

Comment: It is possible, but you'll hate yourself in not even 4 weeks, if you start programming like this. Its a hell to debug (beside other heavy downsides).

Comment: Look for magic methods like __get and __set which allow you what you want to achieve. Or use the stdClass. But be aware that this is not good software design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objects don't exist yet, you need to create them:

```
$info->$foo = new stdClass;
$info->$foo->$bar = new stdClass;
$info->$foo->$bar->$baz = 42;
```

But I don't see the point in doing this over simply using arrays. `stdClass` objects don't really give you any advantage and arrays can be created implicitly to an unlimited depth:

```
$info[$foo][$bar][$baz] = 42;
```